# right aligned nav buttons next to right aligned form

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've got a default Bootstrap navbar with a right-aligned search-form and another few right-aligned nav-buttons. The nav buttons are supposed to right to the search form but they are on the left side, no matter what I do.

**How can I fix that?**

This:

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
</ul>
```

Becomes this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swap their positions.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
</ul>
<form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/timgavin/0Lnqdbd4/